# Заменна определенного сегмена пути без переопределения других

Tags: react-router-dom

Можно ли как-то заменить определенный сегмент пути без указания других?

```
/:type/:hash
/:type/:thread/:hash
/:type/:view/:hash
```

У меня много разных путей, и используя useNavigate я хочу заменить только сегмент :hash текущего пути, но почему-то функция не дает такого сделать. Казалось бы, это очень удобная функция. Есть у кого-то идеи как это сделать без парсинга location или использования useParams? Может есть какие-то плагины или т.п.?